# How to create new webtemplate, inherited from another custom web template?

Tags: custom, web-template

I have a sharepoint 2010 portal styled by someone else. If I am in my sharepoint portal and try to create a new site I see 2 templates. First one is publishing site and the other is a custom template for example "customTemplateA".

I would like to create a new webtemplate, but would like to start from the "customTemplateA" template as start moment. After this I would like to change some styling and remove for example the quiq menu on the left. I dont have skills how to create webtemplates. Can someone tell me please where to begin?

Can I duplicate the custom template?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to read this extensive blogpost [by Vesa](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx). It goes in to great detail about your different options and how to create new WebTemplates.

Regarding basing a WebTemplate on a WebTemplate, that is not possible. A WebTemplate needs to be based on a SiteDefinition.